# Puppeteer: ProtocolError: Waiting for selector failed: Protocol error: Argument should belong to the same JavaScript world as target object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I have created this function:

```js
async function sendRequest(page: Page, url: string) {
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.goto(url),
    page.waitForSelector("div#header"),
  ]);
}
```

When I use this function, NodeJS throws the following error message:

```
ProtocolError: Waiting for selector `div#header` failed: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Argument should belong to the same JavaScript world as target object
    at /home/mble/Code/repos/pluget/services/spigotScraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/Connection.ts:400:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSessionImpl.send (/home/mble/Code/repos/pluget/services/spigotScraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/Connection.ts:396:12)
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (/home/mble/Code/repos/pluget/services/spigotScraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/ExecutionContext.ts:274:44)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at WaitTask.rerun (/home/mble/Code/repos/pluget/services/spigotScraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/WaitTask.ts:123:26)
[ERROR] 18:53:05 ProtocolError: Waiting for selector `div#header` failed: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Argument should belong to the same JavaScript world as target object
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does removing `waitForNav` and the `Promise.all` work? `goto` already does a `waitForNavigation` basically.

Comment: @ggorlen sadly not, both with and without waitForNavigation versions do not work

Comment: btw, i am using fork of puppeteer, called puppeteer-extra, so maybe it is an issue with puppeteer-extra

Comment: @MaciejBledkowski did you find a workaround? It seems to be an issue with puppeteer-extra.

Answer (score 1):

Ahoj Macieji, I am using puppeteer-extra too, but I am not sure if that is the cause. The error, however, is the same as in your case:

> Argument should belong to the same JavaScript world as target object

This happens, after the `page.goto` runs, `page.waitForSelector` is set and then navigation occurs (e.g. from an authentication page, in my case). I guess this results in a "different Javascript world", and the error is triggered.

A workaround for me was to first `page.waitForSelector` and then `page.goto`. Weird, but I hope it works for you too.